# GUI doesn't update while running

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, invoke, inotifypropertychanged

I have a code that connects to the server and get's from it a list of contacts. Iv'e been trying to get it using this function.

```
        public async Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Send the GET_CONTACTS_COMMAND to the server
                await comm.SendMessageAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("GET_CONTACTS"));

                // Wait for and handle the server's response
                string contactsResponse = await comm.ReceiveMessageAsync();

                // Process the server's response
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactsResponse))
                {
                    // Parse the response to get the list of contacts
                    List<Contact> contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(contactsResponse);
                    return contacts;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to fetch contacts from the server");
                    return null; // or throw an exception
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error during contact loading: {ex.Message}");
                return null; // or throw an exception
            }
        }
```

This is where I call it

```
        public async Task LoadChat()
        {
            if (Chats == null)
            {
                Chats = new ObservableCollection<ChatListData>();
                List<Contact> contacts = await GetContactsAsync();
                MessageBox.Show("did");
                Chats.Add(new ChatListData(contacts.ElementAt(0).Username, new Uri("/assets/5.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "hello", DateTime.Now, false));
                OnPropertyChanged("Chats");
            }
        }
```

this is the decleration of Chats

```
public ObservableCollection<ChatListData> Chats { get; set; }
```

```
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

this is the constructor and the init function

```
        public ViewModel(Communicator communicator) 
        {
            comm = communicator;
            Initialize();
            LoadChatConversation();
            LoadStatusThumbs();
        }


        private void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                {
                    if (comm == null)
                    {
                        comm = new Communicator();
                        _ = comm.ConnectToServerAsync();
                    }
                }
                _ = LoadChat();
                //await comm.ConnectToServerAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error during initialization: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

I've tried to run the loadChat that way (to check if the problem might be with the getContacts functions, but it won't work.

```
        public async Task LoadChat()
        {
            if (Chats == null)
            {
                Chats = new ObservableCollection<ChatListData>();
                Chats.Add(new ChatListData("shelly", new Uri("/assets/5.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "hello", DateTime.Now, false));
                OnPropertyChanged("Chats");
            }
        }
```

this is the relevant xaml

```
                <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Chats}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatButtonItemTemplate}"
                Padding="0,15">
                    <ItemsControl.DataContext>
                        <viewmodels:ViewModel/>
                    </ItemsControl.DataContext>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Initialize Chats to the ObservableCollection (as readonly). Then you don't need to trigger OnPropertyChanged for it because it will never change. (It fires its own events when you add to it.)

Comment: but if im initialize Chats to readOnly, how do I add the data that I'm getting from the server? (contacts)

Comment: but what is a problem? the function is not called, the chats is not printed in wpf? if so please add the xaml code as well. the functions has a deadlock?

Comment: Some considerations to improve your code: use the .NET `System.Text.Json` to serialize and deserialize *asynchronously*. Do not replace the ObservableCollection instance. Instead reuse it (Clear, Add). Move the call to `ViewMode.Initialize` to the `Loaded` event. This way you allow the constructor to return quickly. And you can make it async because the event handler can be defined async so that you can properly await the async API.

Comment: Please add all code necessary to reproduce your issue. This also includes how you display the Chat items. just create a new project and incrementally add code until you get the observed behavior.

Comment: @Kaspar the problem is that the data is added to the chats, but it wont show on the xaml, I've added the xaml code to my question

Comment: When you assign a new value to the Chats property, the property setter must fire a change notification, i.e. the PropertyChangedEvent of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. In this case it makes no sense to declare Chats as ObservableCollection (as already said a few days ago). Alternatively make the Chats property readonly, i.e. `public ObservableCollection<ChatListData> Chats { get; } = new();`. When you have new items, `Clear()` the collection and `Add(...)` new items.

Comment: @BionicCode my code is too complicated to create a new one right now, i can provide parts from it but not all of it

Comment: The Initialize method must also be declared async, like `public async Task Initialize()` and await all awaitable method calls made there. Then the method must not be called in a constructor, because a constructor can not be async. This means the view has to call Initialize explicitly after creating an instance of the view model. This can for example be done in an async Loaded event handler.

Comment: @Clemens how can I add items into a readOnly property?

Comment: The readonly property holds an ordinary ObservableCollection where you can add and remove elements. You can however not assign a new collection.